# pyside + py2exe, app crash randomly, without meaningful error messages

Tags: python, py2exe, pyside

I have a pyside python app, which I already do error handling in the main loop as follows.

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
try:
   wg = MyMainWindow(app)
   wg.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
except Exception, e:
   print 'error'
```

When I compiled this app with py2exe, random fatal crash happens some time:
"Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library Runtime Error!"
"This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."

And I couldn't get any meaningful error messages to help me find the root cause of the problem. I have tried to create a core dump from Windows Task Manager but got "Access Denied" error.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: I know this is not what you've asked, but have you considered pyinstaller instead of py2exe?  The only advantage that py2exe has, IMO, is that it's more popular.  In any other respect, pyinstaller is better.  It finds the runtime libraries on its own (manifest and all), it supports eggs quite well, and it has an easy way to tell it that a module needs another module when it doesn't detect the dependency itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install [Visual c++ Runtime Library](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555). 
For more information take a look at the "Providing the Microsoft Visual C runtime DLL" part of the py2exe [tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5).